# Asp.net overriding HTTP Referer

Tags: asp.net

Ideally, I would like to remove/override the HTTP response referer header. My code looks something like:

```
Response.AddHeader("Referer", "");
Response.Redirect(url);
```

I am doing this because I am not running in pipelined mode, so I can't access the header directly.

This doesn't appear to do anything though.

Comment: What are you talking about? There is no Referer header in a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a Response.Redirect, you are sending an http 302 or location changed response to the client.

The client then makes a new request for the location specified in the 302 response.

The referer header will be set by the client. You can't change it that way.